# How do I properly use mod_rewrite here?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'd like to use a .htaccess file to rewrite my URLs like so:

Input: `http://example.com/posts/18/title`

Output: `http://example.com/posts/post.php?id=18&title=title`

I have the .htaccess file placed in the `posts` directory on my webserver.

This the contents of my .htacess file:

```
# Enable Rewriting
RewriteEngine on

# Rewrite post URLs
#   Input:  /posts/18/this-is-the-post-title
#   Output: /posts/post.php?id=18&title=this-is-the-post-title
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=(\d+)&title=([A-Za-z0-9-]+)
RewriteRule ^/posts/post.php /%1/%2? [R=301]
```

When I go to `http://example.com/posts/post.php?id=18&title=title` directly, it instead takes me to `http://example.com/18/title`.

I know I'm making a mistake somewhere, but I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it backwards. Also, if I understand the question correctly, you don't want a 301 redirect, but just an internal change for purposes of Apache and PHP.

What you want to do is this:

```
# Enable Rewriting
RewriteEngine on

# Rewrite post URLs
#   Input:  /posts/18/this-is-the-post-title
#   Output: /posts/post.php?id=18&title=this-is-the-post-title
RewriteRule ^/posts/(\d+)/([^/]+) /posts/post.php?id=$1&title=$2
```

Comment: After applying your rule, going to `http://example.com/posts/post.php?id=18&title=test` works now (the URL is not changed in the browser) but going to `http://example.com/posts/18/title` returns a 404.

Comment: I can't test this right now, but can you try changing the last line to `RewriteRule ^/posts/(\d+)/([^/]+) post.php?id=$1&title=$2`?